# Development Environment - LAMP - Xampp - Mod-Rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am currently attempting to build a development environment using xampp. I have set-up Xampp and connected it to a local copy of the sites database. I am able to  access the the home page when using the following URL: localhost/sitename. However, once I click on any of the links it directs me to an error page that says "The requested URL was not found on this server". The URL it directs me to is localhost/sitename/foldername. The site uses MVC archetecture, so the site should direct the user to the proper controller.

I have ensured i have activated mod_rewrite on the httpd.conf file and placed the .htaccess file within the applications folder. Any other ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe AllowOverride is disable in your apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check if RewriteEngine is on.. Also, make sure that RewriteBase is correct..

Comment: RewriteEngine is on within my .htaccess file. I also have the .htaccess file stored within all the sub-directories. Is there a directory I am missing?